# Import model into RVIZ/MoveIt

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

While trying to import  a model to the planning scene following these steps :
I clicked the tab 'scene objects' and pressed the button 'import from mesh' i can't choose my STL file.
What should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405350/import-model-into-rviz/moveit/) by [TFZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/111570/tfz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2022-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhara](https://answers.ros.org/users/102753/dhara/) on 2022-08-23**:
Hi, are you referring that the window for selecting the mesh files is not appeared? Or your files are not visible?

**Comment by [TFZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/111570/tfz/) on 2022-08-23**:
Hi, actually my files didn't appear cuz  stl was written in uppercase (STL) :/

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2022-08-27**:
Please post that as the answer to your question and accept it, so it is marked as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, actually my files didn't appear cuz stl was written in uppercase (STL)

---

Originally posted by [TFZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/111570/tfz/) with karma: 36 on 2022-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0